# Send array from javascript to php by POST in Joomla 3.x

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, joomla3.0

im trying to send an array from javascript to Joomla 3.x php file.

```
var options = ['foo', 'bar'];

$.post('index.php?option=component&view=componentview&Itemid=123&tmpl=component&layout=xlsx', {'xlsx_options': options})
```

Then, I have a php file which creates data in order to download xlsx file. But I need to filter by this options array and Im not able to retrieve it. I've tried this without success.

```
$xlsx = $_POST['xlsx_options'];
$xlsx = json_decode($_POST['xlsx_options'], true);
$xlsx = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('xlsx_options');
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$j.ajaxSetup({
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
var options = ['foo', 'bar'];
$j.post('index.php?option=component&view=componentview&Itemid=123&tmpl=component&layout=xlsx', JSON.stringify({'xlsx_options': options}));
```

I don't know that you will necessary want to do ajaxSetup if not all of your ajax requests are sending a JSON payload. You can use $.ajax to submit your post request and specify the dataType there, if that is the case (see below)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'index.php?option=component&view=componentview&Itemid=123&tmpl=component&layout=xlsx',
  type:"POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({'xlsx_options': options}),
  contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(){
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Please let me know if this solution worked for you. Thanks!